# Clear each value of each key inside an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I don't figure it out, how to clear each value of each key inside an object.

The result should be like this.

```js
const initialObject = { a: "valueA", b: "valueB", c: "valueC" };

const finalObject = { a: "", b: "", c: "" };
```

I'm using Typescript.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the keys to an array of `[key, ""]` and then convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const initialObject = {a: "valueA",  b: "valueB", c: "valueC"}
        
const finalObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(initialObject)
    .map(key => [key, ""])
)

console.log(finalObject)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Ori.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the `initialObject` keys and for each key create that property in the `finalObject` with a value of empty strings `""`

```js
const initialObject = { a: "valueA", b: "valueB", c: "valueC" };
const finalObject = {};

for (let key in initialObject) {
  finalObject[key]= "";
}

console.log(finalObject);
```